# Pegar os filhos directos do ul

Tags: jquery

Preciso de analisar os filhos directos de um **ul** dá qual estou a fazer **clone()** só que não estou a conseguir obter nenhum resultado.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Menu 1 </li>
  <li> Menu 2 
     <ul>
       <li>Sub-Menu 1</li>
       <li>Sub-Menu 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 3 </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function menu(){
    clone = $( "#menu").clone();
    clone.children("> li").each(function() {
        if($(this).find("ul").length > 0){
            $(this).append("<span>Adiconar Seta</span>");
        } 
    });
}
```

Sabem dizer-me o que estou a fazer de errado?

Comment: Não entendi qual o resultado que vc espera... Qual seria a finalidade desse objeto clonado?

Comment: Vc vai clonar um Menu inteiro que vai ter o mesmo ID do menu clonado e depois que colocar o span solto dentro de uma UL tipo <ul><span></span><li></li></ul>? Esta tudo meio confuso e sem sentido... Explica melhor ai o que vc quer fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa usar `>` no seletor no `.children()`. Se você quer achar os filhos diretos `li` da `ul` clonada, basta apenas usar o seletor `li`:

```
clone.children("li").each(function() {
```

O método `.children()` busca apenas elementos no primeiro nível (filhos diretos), ou seja, `.children("li")` do objeto clonado irá encontrar os seguintes `li`'s:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Menu 1 </li>            ← este
  <li> Menu 2                 ← este
     <ul>
       <li>Sub-Menu 1</li>
       <li>Sub-Menu 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 3 </li>            ← este
</ul>
```

Após clonar o elemento, é preciso inseri-lo em algum lugar. No exemplo abaixo usei `.append()` para inserir no final do `body`.

Seu exemplo:

```js
function menu(){
    clone = $( ".menu").clone();
    clone.children("li").each(function() {
        if($(this).find("ul").length > 0){
            $(this).append("<span>Adiconar Seta</span>");
        } 
    });
    
    $("body").append(clone);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="menu()">Clonar</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 1 </li>
  <li> Menu 2 
     <ul>
       <li>Sub-Menu 1</li>
       <li>Sub-Menu 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 3 </li>
</ul>
```

O problema é que ao clonar `<ul id="menu">` você estará duplicando id's, o que é incorreto no HTML, onde um id deve ser único, embora isso não irá afetar a parte da clonagem, pois o código `$("#menu").clone()` irá apontar sempre para o primeiro `<ul id="menu">`. Porém é melhor trocar o `id="menu"` por `class="menu"`.

Referência:

**[jQuery .children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)**